# I get an error when reloading a page with a QR code

Tags: php, qr-code

I have this code which outputs a QR code:

```
<?php
include(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('Soci', 'Nom', 'Cognoms', 'eCorreu')))
->from($db->quoteName('#__rsform_socis'))
->where($db->quoteName('username') . ' = '. $db->quote($user->username)); 
$db->setQuery($query);
$codeContents = $db->loadObjectList();
$data .= "Soci Nº: {$codeContents[0]->Soci}\n ";
$data .= "Nom: {$codeContents[0]->Nom} ";
$data .= "{$codeContents[0]->Cognoms}\n";
$data .= "e-correu: {$codeContents[0]->eCorreu}";
$tempDir = JPATH_SITE . '/images/'; 
$fileName = 'qr_'.md5($data).'.png'; 
$pngAbsoluteFilePath = $tempDir.$fileName;
$urlRelativeFilePath = JUri::root() .'images/' . $fileName;
if (!file_exists($pngAbsoluteFilePath)) {
QRcode::png($data, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);
} 
echo '<img src="'.$urlRelativeFilePath.'" />';
echo '<br><a href="'.$urlRelativeFilePath.'" download="qrcode.png">Descarrega el carnet</a>';
?>
```

However, when the user reloads the page or goes back to it it gives an error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: data in /home/u916662558/public_html/plugins/system/sourcerer/helper.php(632) : runtime-created function on line 3
```

I guess it has something to do with the fact that the code is already in the file system. How can I get rid of it (the error)?
Thanks,

Dani

Comment: First occurence of `$data` should use assignment instead of concatenation: `$data /*.*/= "Soci Nº: {$codeContents[0]->Soci}\n ";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `$data` at the point you try to self-concatenate:

```
$data .= "Soci Nº: {$codeContents[0]->Soci}\n ";
```

This is the function equivalent of

```
$data = $data . "Soci ...";
        ^^^^----not defined yet
```

Add a var initialization first:

```
$data = ''; //
$data .= etc...
```